# Copy from one worksheet to another plus last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have 28 spreadsheets, all in different folders. Each spreadsheet has a flat list I need to pull into one document and update it every 4 weeks.

I have written the below Macro which I plan to embed in each spreadsheet to copy to 'Planned Loads.xlsx'. I need it to paste to the last row. I have tried a number of things and can't get it to work.

```
Sub Copy_PlannedLoads()
'
' Copy_PlannedLoads Macro
'
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Last_Row As Long

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\peterha\Google Drive\Athlete Development Team\Sport Science\PDMS Data\Planned Load.xlsx")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("Trimp Load Data NEW").Range("PlannedLoad").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Close y:
y.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array variant  is more simple.

```
Sub Copy_PlannedLoads()
    '
    ' Copy_PlannedLoads Macro
    '
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim rngT As Range
    Dim Last_Row As Long

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = ActiveWorkbook
    vDB = x.Sheets("Trimp Load Data NEW").Range("PlannedLoad")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\peterha\Google Drive\Athlete Development Team\Sport Science\PDMS Data\Planned Load.xlsx")

    'Now, copy what you want from x:
    'x.Sheets("Trimp Load Data NEW").Range("PlannedLoad").Copy

    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    Set rngT = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

    'Close y:
    y.Close

End Sub
```